# How to port a locally scaling JVM application to scale in Kubernetes?

Tags: java, kubernetes, scalability, jobrunr

Coming from classic Java application development and being new to "all this cloud stuff", I have a (potentially naive) basic question about scalability e.g. in Kubernetes.

Let's assume I've written an application for the JVM (Java or Kotlin) that scales well locally across CPUs / CPU cores for compute-intensive work that is managed via job queues, where different threads (or processes) take their work items from the queues.

Now, I want to scale the same application beyond the local machine, in the cloud. In my thinking the basic way of working stays the same: There are job queues, and now "cloud nodes" instead of local processes get their work from the queues, requiring some network communication.

As on that high level work organization is basically the same, I was hoping that there would be some JVM framework whose API / interfaces I would simply need to implement, and that framework has then different backends / "engines" that are capable of orchestrating a job queuing system either locally via processes, or in the cloud involving network communication, so my application would "magically" just scale indefinitely depending on now many cloud resources I throw at it (in the end, I want dynamic horizontal auto-scaling in Kubernetes).

Interestingly, I failed to find such a framework, although I was pretty sure that it would be a basic requirement for anyone who wants to bring local applications to the cloud for better scalability. I found e.g. [JobRunr](https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr), which seems to come very close, but unfortunately so far lacks the capability to dynamically ramp up Kubernetes nodes based on load.

Are there other frameworks someone can recommend?

Comment: The whole idea about kubernetes is to break out of the single-instance limitation because that will eventually limit you when you want to scale.  For you, a single JVM.  Instead think, how will my application need to be written when I have thousands of Linux machines to run it on.

Comment: I'm not necessarily stuck to a single JVM... I'm totally open to frameworks that assist you with creating a setup where "compute clients" run in their own JVM instance on Kubernetes nodes / containers, but "register" themselves with some kind of job orchestrator to take part in the workload.

Answer (score 1):

Scale your code as Kubernetes Jobs, try [keda](https://keda.sh/docs/2.4/concepts/scaling-jobs/).

Comment: I've read about KEDA, but, being written in Go, I was wondering how it's supposed to help me scaling a JVM application. I guess the mistake I'm making is to think that the application itself should be responsive for the scaling, whereas the thinking in Kubernetes seems to be that the infrastructure itself should scale (in an programming language agnostic way), and somehow the application should then "just recognize" newly scaled up resources.

Comment: But I'm still wondering why you'd need KEDA if there's already the [POD autoscaler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) in Kubernetes...

Comment: Not a mistake, just a new world. Built-in k8s hpa does not watch event originate from outside the cluster.